# Javascript Prototype select elements by name with mask

Tags: prototypejs

I have several inputs:

```
<input name="row.type[0].value">
<input name="row.type[1].value">
....
<input name="row.type[100].value">
```

How can I to obtain an array with all these inputs?

If with $$-operation, then something like that doesn't work:

```
var cabins = $$('input[name^=row.type[].value]').each(function(row) {
   //stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add a class to all of the input fields you can access them using the class

for instance

```
<input class="rowvalues" name="row.type[0].value">
<input class="rowvalues" name="row.type[1].value">
....
<input class="rowvalues" name="row.type[100].value">
```

then using `$$()`

```
var cabins = $$('.rowvalues').each(function(row){
    //other code
    //row equals the DOM element not the input value
});
```

Answer (score 7):

If all the inputs you want to grab have a name starting with `row.type[`, then you can grab them all using `$$()` like this:

```
var cabins = $$('input[name^="row.type["]');
```